# Aplicación JAVA y servidor HTTP con angular.js, con maven en netbeans

Tags: java, angularjs

? mi pregunta es la siguiente!quiero montar una aplicación JAVA, que levante un servidor http, que el proyecto tambien contenga html con ANGULAR 1 y que el archivo lo levante desde las dependencias de MAVEN en NETBEANS 8.2. Es decir que la dependencia, angular.js, adquitida por MAVEN la pueda utilizar en las html.
Para aclarar un poco aqui el POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BFHSoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sonidoambiental</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
     <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/angular -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
    <artifactId>angular</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>javazoom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>

               </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <fork>false</fork>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental.main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

el main de JAVA es solo una parte, pero es para demostrar la indea, un servidor HTTP:

```
...
public class main {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
         final HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080), 10);
        /* Controlamos el contexto general para descargar archivos estáticos en la ruta actual */
        server.createContext("/", he -> {
            try {
                /* Comprobamos la existencia del archivo a partir de la ruta actual (".") */
                File file = new File("./src/main/java/bfhsoftware/sonidoambiental", he.getRequestURI().getPath());
                if (file.exists()) {
                    /* Obtenemos el tipo mime del archivo para enviarlo en la cabecera correspondiente */
                    he.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", Files.probeContentType(Paths.get(file.getPath())));
                    /* Enviamos las cabeceras HTTP OK junto con la longitud del contenido */
                    he.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, file.length());
                    /* Para no saturar la memoria ni el recolector de basura enviamos el archivo en trozos de 64K */
                    OutputStream output = he.getResponseBody();
                    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
                    final byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    fs.close();
                } else {

....
```

en el proyecto tiene un archivo INDEX.HTML comun casi vacio, al que le quiero agregar el archivo angular.js y este apuntando a la dependencia obtenida por maven

> 

Básicamente colocar la variante STRING que sea que apunta el path de la dependencia. gracias desde ya!

Comment: java es backend, angular es para frontend asi que angular no tiene que pertenecer al POM de dependencias, debes instalar nodejs, npm para lograr lo que buscas

Comment: entonces deberían ser dos proyectos por separado?, recordando que las html se mostraran basados en el servidor de backend, cierto? no se puede colocar todo en un mismo proyecto?

Comment: las cosas deben estar en su lado respectivo

Comment: HA, el usuario no puede ver las dependencias del back-end, entiendo, entonces tengo que buscarla por otro lado, no?

Comment: exactamente, debes comunicar el backend con el frontend con sockets o peticiones REST.

Comment: una repuesta seria como levantar las dependencias con npm, en este caso angular

Comment: puedes revisar mi perfil ahi tengo un proyecto de angular bueno aqui esta el link https://github.com/x-rw/goosip, revisa el package json(ahi estan las dependecias para frontend)